# formatLocalized always gives the result in English

Tags: laravel

If I use `$post->created_at->formatLocalized('%A %e %B')` the result is always in English, even if I set `locale` to `'nl'` in `config/app`.

I have tried adding `\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));` in the `AppServiceProvider` and running `php artisan optimize:clear` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set locale on your Carbon in this way,  as for `Russian` language :

```
@php
   \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('ru');
@endphp

{{ $post->created_at->translatedFormat('%A %e %B') }}
```

Comment: Actually, just using `translatedFormat` instead of `formatLocalized` (without `setLocale ` at the top) did the trick!